# How to print a variable in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am new to Xcode.
I have variables x and y as random numbers from 1 to 100. I want the screen to print x and y when a button is pressed. How do I do that?

my code is:

```
- (IBAction)printtwonumbers:(id)sender;
{
x = arc4random() %100;
y = arc4random() %100;
label1 setText: [x];
label2 setText:[x];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

XenElement is right if you want to print to the log. If you want to set the text of the labels though then your syntax is incorrect. In fact, if you are using that code you are probably getting a bunch of warnings and/or errors.

```
int x = arc4random() %10;
int y = arc4random() %100;
[label1 setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", x];
[label2 setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", y];
```

Take a look at the compiler warnings and you'll see why this code is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Message Here: %d", x);
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by XenElement, NSLog is the basic method for printing to the console. `printf` also works as expected but there's little reason to use it.

I like to use Marcus Zarra's `DLog` macro. It gives a little more information than NSLog and it only prints to the console when you're running a debug build. The source is [available on Marcus' blog](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/02/my-current-prefix-pch-file/).

To set the `DEBUG` flag, go to the build settings for the debug build and enter DEBUG under "Preprocessor Macros".